# Вставка в csv из html

Tags: python, csv, beautiful-soup

Есть файловая структура:

```
files/
├── AAN
│   ├── some1.html
│   └── some2.html
└── AAPL
    ├── some3.html
    └── some4.html
```

Я хочу вытащить header из каждого html и вставить в **Header Analyzer**, но он не отрабатывает. Что я делаю не так?

```
import csv
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory = '/home/achi/Desktop/auca/web_scrap/files'


for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(f'/home/achi/Desktop/auca/web_scrap/summary/{folder}.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(['Foldername', 'Filenames', 'Header analyzed'])

        for filename in os.listdir(f'{directory}/{folder}'):
            if filename.endswith(".HTML"):
                f = open(filename)
                lines = f.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(lines, 'html.parser')
                items = soup.find_all('div',  attrs={'class': 'c4'})
                for item in items:
                    item_text = str(item)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(item_text, 'html.parser')
                    head = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'c6'})
                    for h in head:
                        data = h.get_text()
                        writer.writerow([folder, filename, data])
    csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Что значит не отрабатывает? Больше конкретики

Comment: именно, что он ничего не делает, просто создает пустой csv, даже ошибки нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по файловой структуре, расширение файлов `.html` записано маленькими буквами. В коде аргумент `".HTML"` метода `endswith()` у вас в верхнем регистре. Возможно поэтому условие никогда не выполняется.

Попробуйте заменить

```
if filename.endswith(".HTML"):
```

На

```
if filename.endswith(".html"):
```